# How to run Ajax loading image for Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have a Crystal Report in UpdatePanel. I want to use a ajax loading image when the crystalreportviewer loading data, but my code don't display the image.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnlAll" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlReport" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal" Width="100%">
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crlAll" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" BackColor="AntiqueWhite" HasCrystalLogo="False" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" GroupTreeStyle-BackColor="#CCCCCC" PrintMode="ActiveX" Width="100%" ShowAllPageIds="true" />
      </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="crlAll" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="ajaxUpPro" DynamicLayout="false">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <img src="../Images/ajax-loader1.gif" alt="Loading..."/> Loading...
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="ajaxUpPro" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="uppnlAll"
        DisplayAfter="2">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <center style="height: 115px; width: 123px;" dir="ltr">
                <img id="Img3" alt="Loading" src="Images/ajax-loader1.gif" runat="server" style="vertical-align: middle;
                    height: 71px; width: 100px;" /></center>
            <cc1:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="UpdateProgressVisibilityExtenderLeave3" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="uppnlAll" VerticalSide="Middle" VerticalOffset="0" HorizontalSide="Center"
                HorizontalOffset="0" ScrollEffectDuration=".1" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```